# Distance Primitive not working with Raster information: Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

This one is long so please bear with me. I have Two rasters in my world, one of a department and one of a very important lake (it was a shape file that I rasterized). I load both rasters and use them to set the variable lake (tota) and the elevation. Then Im trying to set the distance between non lake patches and lake patches but Im getting an error "DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
error while patch 571 969 running DISTANCE"

This error doesn't make sense to my as the variable im checking is only for those who have tota (water) I know the code will be long and i tried my best to simplify but it is still a bit cluttered

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ world lake show-lake water]

patches-own[
  distance-water
    tota
  
]

to draw-tota

  let min-elevation gis:minimum-of world
  let max-elevation gis:maximum-of world
  ask patches [
    set elevation gis:raster-sample worldself
    if (elevation <= 0) or (elevation >= 0) [
      set pcolor scale-color green elevation 2900 max-elevation
    ]
  ]
end


to draw-lake
  ask patches [
    set water gis:raster-sample lake self
    if (water >= 0) [
      set pcolor blue
      set tota 1
    ]
  ]
    
end

to setup-map
  
    set world gis:load-dataset "D:/Geografico/DEM_Lago_Tota.asc"
  gis:set-transformation [-72.994844704 -72.835891153 5.418413284 5.648012857666661] [0 1000 0 1000]
  set lake gis:load-dataset "D:/Geografico/Lago_Tota_Raster.asc"
  
  draw-tota
  draw-lake
end
;;set up conditions


to set-houses
ask patches [
    set dano_suelo (1 + random 5) ;; 
    set distance-lake distance min-one-of patches with [tota = 1] [distance myself]
  ]; This is the line that is giving me trouble!
  
set-default-shape turtles "person"

  create-turtles 100

end

to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 1000 0 1000
  
   
  ;set-lago
 ; set-predios
  set-houses
  
     


  
  reset-ticks
end
```

It is a lot, and unfortunately i dont know how to show you a picture. Any guidance will be appreciated as Im really lost. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Now the names are in English, Tota is the name of the lake in question. Thanks Matteo for the tip.

Comment: Haven't fully read the question yet, however I'd advise to use English for naming variables and procedures for the code you post on here. This is *not* required by SO, but there is no doubt that it is [preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/12391423) and that it makes your code more accessible to those to whom you are asking your questions, therefore helping you in the first place. Will take a closer look at the question when I can, anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I know about your problem indicates that there is not always a patch that fulfills the requirements of `min-one-of patches with [tota = 1] [distance myself]`. You could try running the code with an added `if` statement to check for that.

```
ifelse any? patches with [tota = 1] [
   set distancia_agua distance min-one-of patches with [tota = 1] [distance myself]
] [
   set distancia_agua "na"
]
```

As an edit based on your comment:

In order to reduce the number of operations I introduced `let tota-edge <...>`. This means that you check only once which patches qualify as tota rather than doing it 1002001 times (since every single patch would do this same operation). So 1002001 times instead of 1.004006e+12.
I don't know how big tota itself is but if it is a sizable portion of the world, `ask patches with [tota != 1]` will speed up your program some more. Finally, I only used the edges of tota since the middle of the lake is never the closest part of the lake to a non-lake patch.

```
ifelse any? patches with [tota = 1] [
  let tota-edge patches with [tota = 1 and any? neighbors with [tota != 1]] 
  ask patches with [tota != 1] [ set distancia_agua distance min-one-of tota-edge [distance myself] ] 
  ask patches with [tota = 1] [ set distancia_agua 0 ]
] [
  ask patches [ set distancia_agua "na" ]
]
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks Leirs for your answer, ive tried it but when i click the setup botton it just loads, I dont know if calculating the distance for every patch takes alot of time, or if i need to do something to make the code more efficient.

Comment: I need to stablish that the further you are from the lake the more expensive water becomes, if you know a way to do this would be amazing! thanks

Comment: @bksnlow yeah that definitely takes a lot of time. we are talking about 1002001 patches checking if 1002001 patches have tota 1  and then measuring the distance to all tota patches.

Comment: I added some changes to make it quicker. i didn't test the code here since my computer won't even let me create a world with 1002001 patches

Comment: This totally worked!, and i input a smaller raster and it seems to be a lot faster. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @bksnlow I think there was an error in my code (the let `tota-edge <...>` was called multiple times). It should run faster with this edited.

Comment: What do you mean with multiple times if all patches with the condition have to run it? Thanks for the edit, know its taking just 20 minutes to setup, which is a great improvement!

Comment: @bksnlow I had accidentelly put `let tota-edge <...>`  within the command block of `ask patches with [tota != 1][...]`. This meant that every patch was once again defining tota-edge, which was completely unnecessary. With the current edit, tota-edge is only defined once